# Framing new wall/door

Tags: framing

I have a dining room that I want to convert into a home office. There are two openings that I would like to close up and put doors in.

Here is a rendering of both locations:
[image: First Opening]
[image: Second Opening]

I made an attempt at what the framing would look like.

For the first opening:

[image]

And the second opening:

[image]

Do these openings look right? The inner frames are outlines of the prehung doors that I plan on putting there. For the smaller opening, there isn't enough room in between the wall and the door frame to insert anything but shims. Will that be okay? Also, for the larger opening, can I get away with not screwing into the floor?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Good answer below from @Damon... the only thing I'd do differently is have a double bottom plate, with the first part anchored first. When you run the very bottom plate full width and cut the opening (sawzall/reciprocating saw) after everything else is done, you get better fastening to the floor and better planar alignment of the two sides. Also, if you build the walls on the floor, it gives you room to tilt the wall into place (which is not something you get when you build full height and try to tilt it).

Answer (score 1):

Framing like that looks fine and is standard.  Just put a single 2x flat at the top of the jamb instead of 2 and nail up into the cripples above it.

As for the screwing into the floor, the closer you can get a screw or nail into the floor the better.  We usually shoot some nails at an angle (toenail) at the bottom plate on each side of the opening.

Other than that get your measurements right and you should be good to go.